# 'str' object is not callable - iterating over a string, assigning value to each element of the string and returning sum

Tags: python, oop

```
class CoinCollector:

    def __init(self):
        self.total = 0

    def parseChange(self, coins):

            for element in coins:
                if coins(element) == P:
                    self.total += .01
                if coins(element) == N:
                    self.total += .05
                if coins(element) == D:
                    self.total += .10
                if coins(element) == Q:
                    self.total += .25
                if coins(element) == H:
                    self.total += .50
                if coins(element) == W:
                    self.total += 1.00

            return self.total

change = CoinCollector()
change.parseChange('PND')
```

error text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gtorr\Desktop\School\Merrimack Masters\CSC6003OA\Final Project\CoinCollector.py", line 26, in <module>
    change.parseChange('PND')
  File "C:\Users\gtorr\Desktop\School\Merrimack Masters\CSC6003OA\Final Project\CoinCollector.py", line 10, in parseChange
    if coins(element) == P:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is not understanding iteration in python.

The following:

```py
for char in 'abc':
    print(char)
```

prints 'a', 'b' and 'c' on subsequent lines.

Also literal letter `P`, for example, refers to variable named `P`, not to char "P".

So you don't need to use indexed access (and even if not, access by index uses square brackets (`collection[i]`), not parentheses).

```
def parseChange(self, coins):
    for coin in coins:
        if coin == 'P':
            self.total += .01
        elif coin == 'N':
            self.total += .05
        elif coin == 'D':
            self.total += .10
        elif coin == 'Q':
            self.total += .25
        elif coin == 'H':
            self.total += .50
        elif coin == 'W':
            self.total += 1.00

    return self.total
```

However, for better readability and maintainability I'd suggest using dictionary instead:

```py
class CoinCollector:
    COIN_VALUES = {
        'P': 0.01,
        'N': 0.05,
        'D': 0.1,
        'Q': 0.25,
        'H': 0.5,
        'W': 1.0,
    }

    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0

    def parse_change(self, coins):
        for coin in coins:
            self.total += self.COIN_VALUES.get(coin, 0)
        return self.total
```

(variables and functions should be `lower_case_with_underscores` in Python)

Comment: My professor wants me to use a class for the coin collector... Otherwise my first thought was a dictionary to assign coin values to each letter.